# How to set UIlabel TextColor Dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I have created more than one label using this code,

.H file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSArray * phraseAry ;
    UIView * containerView;
    UILabel * oldLabel;
    NSMutableArray *dataArray;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScrollView;
```

.M file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    heightValue = 20;
    widthValue = 0;
    xValue = 5;
    yValue = 10;

containerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<phraseAry.count; i++) {
        widthValue = [self returnWidth:[phraseAry objectAtIndex:i]];

        int newXValue = xValue+widthValue+5;

        //NSLog(@"newXValue : %i",newXValue);
        if (newXValue > 310) {
            yValue +=20;
            xValue = 5;
            newXValue = xValue+widthValue+5;
            UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xValue, yValue, widthValue, heightValue)];
            lbl.text = [phraseAry objectAtIndex:i];
            [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0]];
            lbl.tag = i;
            lbl.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(92/255.0) green:(109/255.0) blue:(43/255.0) alpha:1];
            [containerView addSubview:lbl];
            xValue = newXValue;
        } else {
            UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xValue, yValue, widthValue, heightValue)];
            lbl.text = [phraseAry objectAtIndex:i];
            [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0]];
            lbl.tag = i;
            lbl.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(92/255.0) green:(109/255.0) blue:(43/255.0) alpha:1];
            [containerView addSubview:lbl];
            xValue = newXValue;
        }
    }

    containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, yValue);
    //add code to customize, e.g. polygonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.myScrollView addSubview:containerView];
    self.myScrollView.contentSize = containerView.frame.size;
}
```

And than i set background color and textcolor in specific table using this code

```
- (void)updateLabelMethod
 {
            oldLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[containerView viewWithTag:2];
            oldLabel = label;
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(98/255.0) green:(147/255.0) blue:(216/255.0) alpha:1];
            label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

It will update background of label fine but when i use this code to update textcolor it will display error like this

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setTextColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbaa3b30'

Any ways to set textcolor? Plz help.

Comment: It seems that the label instance variable which you are casting to UILabel is in fact not of UILabel class, but UIView instead.

Comment: UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[containerView viewWithTag:2]; check this really a lable ?  check it using  isKindOfClass :)

Comment: try clear your project and build again. its working fine in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[containerView viewWithTag:2];

check container view has only one view that is a label with tag 2.
May be some other view is set with tag 2 and may be causing the issue.

```
NSLog(@"%@",label);
```

can give you what the label here gives the output .It should point out an `UILabel` itself

make use of  `isKindOfClass:` to identify it is a label you are updating

Comment: No actually am setting that value using count i have set `2` for example and rather than label i dont set any view tag in my app

Comment: Your `NSLog` code gives me list of my label which will be selected using the value of count in my case the first one is view i don't know why bcoz as i said rather than label i don't give tag to any other object. So i have just implement logic to neglaect the the code when count is `0` and its worked. thanx....

Answer (score 3):

Start your label tag from 1 instead of 0, because by default the tag value is 0 for all view.

```
lbl.tag = i+1;
```

Because

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[containerView viewWithTag:0];
```

it will return `containerView` itself, and `UIView` not have `textColor` property :P

Comment: Thanx for reply, now i see why my when i added `nslog` as Lithu T.V suggest than my first value which is for 0 is always UIView. thanx again ..+1

Comment: but dude after implement this you don't need isKindOfClass :D

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (UILable *lblTemp in containerView.subviews){
     if ([lblTemp isKindOfClass:[UILable class]] && lblTemp.tag==2){
         // change the lbl color
        break;
     }
  }
```

check using this code ;)

Comment: I think this is best and sort answer thanx, +1